# Receiving NoMethod Error in Posts#New for Post Monthly Quota method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently trying to limit the amount of posts a user can make per month. But, I can't seem to get the view to recognize that the post quota method is in the **post.rb** model file. I tried a few different approaches, but the code continues to throw the error. How can I get the post quota method to fire off, before the post limit is reached? The error and code are below.

error

```
undefined method `user_basic_post_quota?' for #<Post:0xac6a730>
```

post.rb

```
def self.user_basic_post_quota?
    if current_user.subscription_plan.stripe_id == 1 && current_user.posts.where(:created_at => (Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month..Time.zone.now)).count >= 200
      errors.add(:base, "Exceeded The Amount of Posts That You Can Create For Your Account!")
    end
  end
```

post _form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post) do |f| %>
    <% if f.object.user_basic_post_quota? %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-6">
        <%= f.error_notification %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% else %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-5">
        <label for="post-title">Post Title</label>
        <%= f.input :post_title, class: 'form-control', label: false, required: true, placeholder: '' %>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

posts_controller.rb

```
 # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end
```

NEW APPROACH

post.rb

```
def user_basic_post_quota?
    if current_user.subscription_plan.id == 2 && current_user.posts.where(:created_at => (Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month..Time.zone.now)).count >= 800
      errors.add(:base, "Exceeded The Amount of Post That You Can Create For Your Account!")
    end
  end
```

Error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `subscription_plan' for nil:NilClass):
    1: <div class="container">
    2:   <%= simple_form_for(@post) do |f| %>
    3:     <% if f.object.user_basic_post_quota? %>
    4:     <div class="form-group">
    5:       <div class="col-6">
    6:         <%= f.error_notification %>
```

**If you have a better approach, please inform me.**

Comment: Please add your `PostsController#new` action code

Comment: I updated my code to include the new action.

Answer (score 0):

In your models you can't use `current_user`. You may pass it to the method though. Then your method will look like

```
def user_basic_post_quota?(user)
  if user.subscription_plan.id == 2 && user.posts.where(:created_at => (Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month..Time.zone.now)).count >= 800
    errors.add(:base, "Exceeded The Amount of Post That You Can Create For Your Account!")
  end
end
```

and you'll be able to call it from your controller (where `current_user` is present) like

`Post.user_basic_post_quota?(current_user)`

then your action will be

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
  @quota_exceeded = Post.user_basic_post_quota?(current_user)
end
```

and your view

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post) do |f| %>
    <% if @quota_exceeded %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-6">
        <%= f.error_notification %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% else %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-5">
        <label for="post-title">Post Title</label>
        <%= f.input :post_title, class: 'form-control', label: false, required: true, placeholder: '' %>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

But I believe your `user_basic_post_quota?` method is designed for custom validation because it adds the errors to `Post` object by condition. But it doesn't really supposed to be called other than for `Post` objects validation in this case.

Nevertheless if you want to just check if the quota exceeded your method may look like

```
def user_basic_post_quota?(user)
  user.subscription_plan.id == 2 && user.posts.where(:created_at => (Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month..Time.zone.now)).count >= 800
end
```

Then it will just return `true` if quota is exceeded and `false` otherwise.

Comment: Would it be best to use an ActiveRecord validator instead? validate :user_basic_post_quota, on: :create. No errors are being thrown when it validates through activerecord and not the view itself. I will have to run a spec to test it.

Comment: If you need to validate `Post` objects then you just need to use your method  for custom validation like following: `validate :user_basic_post_quota?` in your `models/post.rb`. But how would you pass `current_user` in that way?

Comment: with user.subscription_plan.id == 2. It works. current_user.subscription_plan.id == 2, shows the error.

Comment: Again you don't have `current_user` in your models. But you may pass `current_user` as `user` and use it in your method in your model. You may pass not only `current_user` but literally every user. For example you may call your method  like `Post.user_basic_post_quota?(User.first)`. So `current_user.subscription_plan.id == 2` doesn't make sense and it actually shouldn't.

Comment: Glad to help you

Comment: I also would appreciate if you accept my answer and maybe upvote it if you found it useful. Cheers!